# Как можно конвертировать размер файла?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Вывожу на jsp страницу файлы, и размер выводится в байтах. Как можно реализовать на jsp, чтоб байты конвертировались и подставлялось автоматом KB/MB/G?

```
<td>${files.length()}</td>
```

Порылся решил попробовать использовать `jsp:useBean` и

```
FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(long size)
```

из библиотеке `commons-io` . Но без результатов, не знаю как это реализовать правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал сделать так.

jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="convertSize" class="ru.project.util.ConvertSize"/>
<c:set target="${convertSize}" property="size" value="${file.length()}"/>
<td>${convertSize}</td>
```

ConvertSize

```
public class ConvertSize {

    private long size;

    public ConvertSize() {
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size);
    }

}
```

6 MB

0 bytes

8 bytes